# jQuery Console Error: It's grabbing images that don't exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, console.log

Thanks for any help or guidance first of all.

We run a Shopify store and we're getting console errors. They all say:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () ... blue.png
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () ... red.png
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () ... green.png

Nothing seems to be showing up incorrectly on the site, and it seems to be happening only on pages that have products. **I expect it be caused by code in the background that's cycling through and grabbing product info including images**. But because everything is showing up fine, I don't know why/where it's trying to GET the images.

I read some *'how to fix console error articles'* online that (I think) helped me determine the line of code that's causing the issue. I could be wrong. I activated "*pause on caught exceptions"* and it stopped on this:

- It's a jQuery v1.11.2 file.
- Everything below was marked with the squiggly red line, with a tooltip indicating it was the source of the error.
- This code appears at the very end of the file.

  1. Is it actually being caused by the jQuery file itself, or something that's calling the jQuery script to run a function?
  2. If it's the latter, how to I find out what's calling the jQuery file?
  3. How do I go about fixing the issue?

Thanks for any help or guidance in helping me figure this out.

```
{return a.offsetWidth <= 0 && a.offsetHeight <= 0 || !k.reliableHiddenOffsets() && "none" === (a.style && a.style.display || m.css(a, "display"))
}, m.expr.filters.visible = function(a) {
    return !m.expr.filters.hidden(a)
};
var Qc = /%20/g,
    Rc = /\[\]$/,
    Sc = /\r?\n/g,
    Tc = /^(?:submit|button|image|reset|file)$/i,
    Uc = /^(?:input|select|textarea|keygen)/i;

function Vc(a, b, c, d) {
    var e;
    if (m.isArray(b)) m.each(b, function(b, e) {
        c || Rc.test(a) ? d(a, e) : Vc(a + "[" + ("object" == typeof e ? b : "") + "]", e, c, d)
    });
    else if (c || "object" !== m.type(b)) d(a, b);
    else
        for (e in b) Vc(a + "[" + e + "]", b[e], c, d)
}
m.param = function(a, b) {
    var c, d = [],
        e = function(a, b) {
            b = m.isFunction(b) ? b() : null == b ? "" : b, d[d.length] = encodeURIComponent(a) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(b)
        };
    if (void 0 === b && (b = m.ajaxSettings && m.ajaxSettings.traditional), m.isArray(a) || a.jquery && !m.isPlainObject(a)) m.each(a, function() {
        e(this.name, this.value)
    });
    else
        for (c in a) Vc(c, a[c], b, e);
    return d.join("&").replace(Qc, "+")
}, m.fn.extend({
    serialize: function() {
        return m.param(this.serializeArray())
    },
    serializeArray: function() {
        return this.map(function() {
            var a = m.prop(this, "elements");
            return a ? m.makeArray(a) : this
        }).filter(function() {
            var a = this.type;
            return this.name && !m(this).is(":disabled") && Uc.test(this.nodeName) && !Tc.test(a) && (this.checked || !W.test(a))
        }).map(function(a, b) {
            var c = m(this).val();
            return null == c ? null : m.isArray(c) ? m.map(c, function(a) {
                return {
                    name: b.name,
                    value: a.replace(Sc, "\r\n")
                }
            }) : {
                name: b.name,
                value: c.replace(Sc, "\r\n")
            }
        }).get()
    }
}), m.ajaxSettings.xhr = void 0 !== a.ActiveXObject ? function() {
    return !this.isLocal && /^(get|post|head|put|delete|options)$/i.test(this.type) && Zc() || $c()
} : Zc;
var Wc = 0,
    Xc = {},
    Yc = m.ajaxSettings.xhr();
a.attachEvent && a.attachEvent("onunload", function() {
    for (var a in Xc) Xc[a](void 0, !0)
}), k.cors = !!Yc && "withCredentials" in Yc, Yc = k.ajax = !!Yc, Yc && m.ajaxTransport(function(a) {
    if (!a.crossDomain || k.cors) {
        var b;
        return {
            send: function(c, d) {
                var e, f = a.xhr(),
                    g = ++Wc;
                if (f.open(a.type, a.url, a.async, a.username, a.password), a.xhrFields)
                    for (e in a.xhrFields) f[e] = a.xhrFields[e];
                a.mimeType && f.overrideMimeType && f.overrideMimeType(a.mimeType), a.crossDomain || c["X-Requested-With"] || (c["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest");
                for (e in c) void 0 !== c[e] && f.setRequestHeader(e, c[e] + "");
                f.send(a.hasContent && a.data || null), b = function(c, e) {
                    var h, i, j;
                    if (b && (e || 4 === f.readyState))
                        if (delete Xc[g], b = void 0, f.onreadystatechange = m.noop, e) 4 !== f.readyState && f.abort();
                        else {
                            j = {}, h = f.status, "string" == typeof f.responseText && (j.text = f.responseText);
                            try {
                                i = f.statusText
                            } catch (k) {
                                i = ""
                            }
                            h || !a.isLocal || a.crossDomain ? 1223 === h && (h = 204) : h = j.text ? 200 : 404
                        }
                    j && d(h, i, j, f.getAllResponseHeaders())
                }, a.async ? 4 === f.readyState ? setTimeout(b) : f.onreadystatechange = Xc[g] = b : b()
            },
            abort: function() {
                b && b(void 0, !0)
            }
        }
    }
});

function Zc() {
    try {
        return new a.XMLHttpRequest
    } catch (b) {}
}

function $c() {
    try {
        return new a.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    } catch (b) {}
}
m.ajaxSetup({
    accepts: {
        script: "text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript"
    },
    contents: {
        script: /(?:java|ecma)script/
    },
    converters: {
        "text script": function(a) {
            return m.globalEval(a), a
        }
    }
}), m.ajaxPrefilter("script", function(a) {
    void 0 === a.cache && (a.cache = !1), a.crossDomain && (a.type = "GET", a.global = !1)
}), m.ajaxTransport("script", function(a) {
    if (a.crossDomain) {
        var b, c = y.head || m("head")[0] || y.documentElement;
        return {
            send: function(d, e) {
                b = y.createElement("script"), b.async = !0, a.scriptCharset && (b.charset = a.scriptCharset), b.src = a.url, b.onload = b.onreadystatechange = function(a, c) {
                    (c || !b.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test(b.readyState)) && (b.onload = b.onreadystatechange = null, b.parentNode && b.parentNode.removeChild(b), b = null, c || e(200, "success"))
                }, c.insertBefore(b, c.firstChild)
            },
            abort: function() {
                b && b.onload(void 0, !0)
            }
        }
    }
});
var _c = [],
    ad = /(=)\?(?=&|$)|\?\?/;
m.ajaxSetup({
    jsonp: "callback",
    jsonpCallback: function() {
        var a = _c.pop() || m.expando + "_" + vc++;
        return this[a] = !0, a
    }
}), m.ajaxPrefilter("json jsonp", function(b, c, d) {
    var e, f, g, h = b.jsonp !== !1 && (ad.test(b.url) ? "url" : "string" == typeof b.data && !(b.contentType || "").indexOf("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") && ad.test(b.data) && "data");
    return h || "jsonp" === b.dataTypes[0] ? (e = b.jsonpCallback = m.isFunction(b.jsonpCallback) ? b.jsonpCallback() : b.jsonpCallback, h ? b[h] = b[h].replace(ad, "$1" + e) : b.jsonp !== !1 && (b.url += (wc.test(b.url) ? "&" : "?") + b.jsonp + "=" + e), b.converters["script json"] = function() {
        return g || m.error(e + " was not called"), g[0]
    }, b.dataTypes[0] = "json", f = a[e], a[e] = function() {
        g = arguments
    }, d.always(function() {
        a[e] = f, b[e] && (b.jsonpCallback = c.jsonpCallback, _c.push(e)), g && m.isFunction(f) && f(g[0]), g = f = void 0
    }), "script") : void 0
}), m.parseHTML = function(a, b, c) {
    if (!a || "string" != typeof a) return null;
    "boolean" == typeof b && (c = b, b = !1), b = b || y;
    var d = u.exec(a),
        e = !c && [];
    return d ? [b.createElement(d[1])] : (d = m.buildFragment([a], b, e), e && e.length && m(e).remove(), m.merge([], d.childNodes))
};
var bd = m.fn.load;
m.fn.load = function(a, b, c) {
    if ("string" != typeof a && bd) return bd.apply(this, arguments);
    var d, e, f, g = this,
        h = a.indexOf(" ");
    return h >= 0 && (d = m.trim(a.slice(h, a.length)), a = a.slice(0, h)), m.isFunction(b) ? (c = b, b = void 0) : b && "object" == typeof b && (f = "POST"), g.length > 0 && m.ajax({
        url: a,
        type: f,
        dataType: "html",
        data: b
    }).done(function(a) {
        e = arguments, g.html(d ? m("<div>").append(m.parseHTML(a)).find(d) : a)
    }).complete(c && function(a, b) {
        g.each(c, e || [a.responseText, b, a])
    }), this
}, m.each(["ajaxStart", "ajaxStop", "ajaxComplete", "ajaxError", "ajaxSuccess", "ajaxSend"], function(a, b) {
    m.fn[b] = function(a) {
        return this.on(b, a)
    }
}), m.expr.filters.animated = function(a) {
    return m.grep(m.timers, function(b) {
        return a === b.elem
    }).length
};
var cd = a.document.documentElement;

function dd(a) {
    return m.isWindow(a) ? a : 9 === a.nodeType ? a.defaultView || a.parentWindow : !1
}
m.offset = {
    setOffset: function(a, b, c) {
        var d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k = m.css(a, "position"),
            l = m(a),
            n = {};
        "static" === k && (a.style.position = "relative"), h = l.offset(), f = m.css(a, "top"), i = m.css(a, "left"), j = ("absolute" === k || "fixed" === k) && m.inArray("auto", [f, i]) > -1, j ? (d = l.position(), g = d.top, e = d.left) : (g = parseFloat(f) || 0, e = parseFloat(i) || 0), m.isFunction(b) && (b = b.call(a, c, h)), null != b.top && (n.top = b.top - h.top + g), null != b.left && (n.left = b.left - h.left + e), "using" in b ? b.using.call(a, n) : l.css(n)
    }
}, m.fn.extend({
    offset: function(a) {
        if (arguments.length) return void 0 === a ? this : this.each(function(b) {
            m.offset.setOffset(this, a, b)
        });
        var b, c, d = {
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            },
            e = this[0],
            f = e && e.ownerDocument;
        if (f) return b = f.documentElement, m.contains(b, e) ? (typeof e.getBoundingClientRect !== K && (d = e.getBoundingClientRect()), c = dd(f), {
            top: d.top + (c.pageYOffset || b.scrollTop) - (b.clientTop || 0),
            left: d.left + (c.pageXOffset || b.scrollLeft) - (b.clientLeft || 0)
        }) : d
    },
    position: function() {
        if (this[0]) {
            var a, b, c = {
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0
                },
                d = this[0];
            return "fixed" === m.css(d, "position") ? b = d.getBoundingClientRect() : (a = this.offsetParent(), b = this.offset(), m.nodeName(a[0], "html") || (c = a.offset()), c.top += m.css(a[0], "borderTopWidth", !0), c.left += m.css(a[0], "borderLeftWidth", !0)), {
                top: b.top - c.top - m.css(d, "marginTop", !0),
                left: b.left - c.left - m.css(d, "marginLeft", !0)
            }
        }
    },
    offsetParent: function() {
        return this.map(function() {
            var a = this.offsetParent || cd;
            while (a && !m.nodeName(a, "html") && "static" === m.css(a, "position")) a = a.offsetParent;
            return a || cd
        })
    }
}), m.each({
    scrollLeft: "pageXOffset",
    scrollTop: "pageYOffset"
}, function(a, b) {
    var c = /Y/.test(b);
    m.fn[a] = function(d) {
        return V(this, function(a, d, e) {
            var f = dd(a);
            return void 0 === e ? f ? b in f ? f[b] : f.document.documentElement[d] : a[d] : void(f ? f.scrollTo(c ? m(f).scrollLeft() : e, c ? e : m(f).scrollTop()) : a[d] = e)
        }, a, d, arguments.length, null)
    }
}), m.each(["top", "left"], function(a, b) {
    m.cssHooks[b] = Lb(k.pixelPosition, function(a, c) {
        return c ? (c = Jb(a, b), Hb.test(c) ? m(a).position()[b] + "px" : c) : void 0
    })
}), m.each({
    Height: "height",
    Width: "width"
}, function(a, b) {
    m.each({
        padding: "inner" + a,
        content: b,
        "": "outer" + a
    }, function(c, d) {
        m.fn[d] = function(d, e) {
            var f = arguments.length && (c || "boolean" != typeof d),
                g = c || (d === !0 || e === !0 ? "margin" : "border");
            return V(this, function(b, c, d) {
                var e;
                return m.isWindow(b) ? b.document.documentElement["client" + a] : 9 === b.nodeType ? (e = b.documentElement, Math.max(b.body["scroll" + a], e["scroll" + a], b.body["offset" + a], e["offset" + a], e["client" + a])) : void 0 === d ? m.css(b, c, g) : m.style(b, c, d, g)
            }, b, f ? d : void 0, f, null)
        }
    })
}), m.fn.size = function() {
    return this.length
}, m.fn.andSelf = m.fn.addBack, "function" == typeof define && define.amd && define("jquery", [], function() {
    return m
});
var ed = a.jQuery,
    fd = a.$;
return m.noConflict = function(b) {
return a.$ === m && (a.$ = fd), b && a.jQuery === m && (a.jQuery = ed), m
}, typeof b === K && (a.jQuery = a.$ = m), m
});
```

Comment: could it be a plugin? Disable the plugins

Comment: @epascarello Hmm. I will try isolating plugins on a test theme and see if that could be the source. Good idea.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks so much! I was able to locate the offending code. There was a colour-swatch code (that we aren't using) that was trying to grab colours to display for the swatch!

Comment: did you check the last email ? The error messages are not from Infinite Options, and appear to be related to an app with an abbreviation of "wlm" and a pre-order app. can you please keep investigating ?

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` shouldn't be grabbing any files all by itself.

Following are the things that you can try.

1. You can click on the error in chrome console, that will take you to the error location in the scripts. Sometimes it will take you to the function which handles the error and not the one which causes it. In this case follow second.
2. You can expand the `Stacktrace` in the console to see the call stack and verify if there are functions in the call stack which are loading these images.
3. You can check under the Network tab to check the call to the images. In Chrome Network console you would see the a column named `Initiator` (After Name,Status,Type). If you click on the link in this column against the image call, you chrome will open then script and move cursor to the line which initiated the call to image. If source code there is minified you can click on the `{}` (Pretty Print) icon at the bottom of source code editor. That will format the code, then you will be able to pin point the source code line that's causing the issue.
4. Finally brute force, check for the references to the `blue.png` or any other files in your source code.

Comment: 1. When I did this, it linked to a file hierarchy that went: Frame - Images - 'Missing Image File'. Unfortunately there wasn't more info to gather here.
2. There was nothing to expand for some reason.
3. It actually links to a new file now: 'bootstrap.min.js'. This is strange because bootstrap is the responsive framework isn't it? It shouldn't be grabbing anything either right?
4. There is nothing referencing these pictures specifically.

Comment: I would suspect `bootstrap`, however bootstrap itself won't be loading the images. Some component provided by it is probably causing the issue. You can create a break point in the step 3, and check for the call stack in panel on the bottom right corner.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to locate the offending code. There was a colour-swatch code (that we aren't using) that was trying to grab colours to display for the swatch!